# Object in inline onclick event

Tags: javascript, onclick

Why is this not working ?

```
<img id="xx" src="/Content/components/imgs/add.gif" onclick='ShowLookup({"id": "22","name": "Robert Pitt"})' />
```

or

```
<img id="xx" src="/Content/components/imgs/add.gif" onclick='ShowLookup("id": "22","name": "Robert Pitt")' />
```

When I click on the image I got an error: Invalid property id

Comment: Can you show us your `ShowLookup` function?

Comment: ShowLookup is empty for now. The error occurs when I clik on the image

Comment: Why do you want to use an object there? The function probably would require normal parameters. Else try ShowLookup(new {"id": "22","name": "Robert Pitt"})

Comment: @Rob: `new {"id": "22","name": "Robert Pitt"}` is definitely wrong.

Comment: @felix, why? isn't he just creating an new object?

Comment: @Rob: `{"id": "22","name": "Robert Pitt"}` is already an object. One uses `new` when creating an object via a constructor function. E.g.: `function Foo() {this.bar = 42;}; var t = new Foo();`. Just type `new {"id": "22","name": "Robert Pitt"}` in the console and you will get the error: *TypeError: object is not a function*.

Comment: @Felix ah ok, I get it. Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

Works like a charm for me :

http://jsfiddle.net/neebz/uwywG/1/

Comment: over here only in IE8 and Chrome. No response in FF